# How to log pymongo queries?

Tags: django, pymongo

In Django default database drivers there is a list of raw queries against the database in [`django.db.connection.queries`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133627/using-django-db-connection-queries).

Is there anything similar in the MongoDB driver pymongo that can be turned on for a single Django http round-trip?

More specifically, I had a [useful middleware](https://gist.github.com/1229685) that showed a list of SQL queries for Django supported RDBs, and I would like to have the same thing for our API stack that uses pymongo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Created my own Django middleware that instruments `pymongo.connection.Connection._send_message()` to record queries into Django's `connection.queries`.

Stored as [sql_mongodb_dump_middleware.py](https://gist.github.com/1589672) in a gist for whoever is interested, comments are welcome.

Answer (score -2):

You can also run:

> mongod -vv  (or more -vvvvv)

to have the server log the queries.

Take a look at this thread:

> https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/OKlfkDjZFso

It has some interesting insights. It points to: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler that shows off some native mongo functions to log queries, and slow queries in particular.

Comment: But that would log ALL the queries, which is really not what I want. As I want to get just the queries used in a specific request round trip.