# Timing Django DB Queries

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm attempting to benchmark the speed of several different queries which return the same thing on Django 1.4 with Postgres. Unfortunately, if I use:

```
 import logging
 l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
 l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
 l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

Two equivalent or similar queries, end up getting deferred to the Query cache. Any way I can clear this cache or have a better way of comparing the speed of two queries?

Comment: I would most definitely like to know as well. +1

Comment: Why not install [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar)

Comment: Already have django-debug-toolbar installed, but it does not work in many instances (ie. AJAX requests), and is not really efficient in benchmarking queries since I need to load them into a view and manually test. Also, if you run two of the same queries, since its cached, the time for the second query will be significantly shorter.

Comment: You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346124/how-do-i-force-django-to-ignore-any-caches-and-reload-data

Comment: You should never time ajax requests since they are async by nature. using the timeit module in python would help you time a view's execution time though.

Comment: Why should I not be able to benchmark the db queries? AJAX aside, how would I measure the time of a query for a normal synchronous request more than once if the query-set is cached.

Comment: Use the timeit module. Then you can see how long something completes in.

Comment: The issue is that even with timeit, if the queryset is cached, it would still take less time than the first load.

Comment: Please come to the Python chat room :)

Answer (score 5):

For my analysis I used something like this:

```
from django import db
for query in db.connections['default'].queries:
    print query, query['time']
```

Comment: Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133627/using-django-db-connection-queries

Comment: This solution has the same issue as mine and the above suggestion, which is that since Django caches querysets, if you run the same or similar operation twice within a fixed period of time, the retrieval times will significantly differ ):