# Method GET not allowed in DRF ViewSet when trying to retrieve single resource

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am new Python and Django. I have created ViewSet as follows:

**api/views.py**

```
class UserDetails(ViewSet):
"""
CREATE, SELECT, UPDATE OR DELETE
"""

def retrive(self, request, pk):
    user = self.get_object(pk)
    print(user.query)
    user = TestSerializer(user)
    return Response(user.data)

def list(self, request):
    users = TestTB.objects.all()
    print(users.query)
    serializer = TestSerializer(users, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def create(self, request):
    serializer = TestSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def update(self, request, pk):
    user = self.get_object(pk)
    serializer = TestSerializer(user, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def destroy(self, request, pk):
    user = self.get_object(pk)
    user.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

def get_object(self, pk):
    try:
        return TestTB.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except TestTB.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

**api/urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserDetails, base_name='user-details')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

This works fine with POST request to create new resource, GET request to get all resources, PUT request to update resource and DELETE request to delete resource. But how can I retrieve single resource? When I make request like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/` than it shows error -

> {
>       "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
>   }

It means that retrieve() method in UserDetails is never called. I know I am missing something, but not able to figure out what.

Comment: Change 'retrive' to 'retrieve', seems like a typo to me

Comment: Add serializer and queryset and remove all methods when u don't need override them :)

Comment: @Noshii Great! It was silly typo error. But than `print(user.query)` is throwing error. Is there any other way to view which query is getting fired?

Comment: `user` is not a queryset.

Comment: @Thaian This was just test. I will need them afterwards when I will have to fire complex custom queries.

Comment: @SachinKukreja I know that, `user` is an object. But I am asking that how to view query in that case?

Comment: Use `django.db.connection` for the queries.

Comment: You can also install [Django Debug Toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar). Ref: [Using django.db.connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133627/using-django-db-connection-queries)

Comment: @Thaian By the way, by adding queryset to the ViewSet, which will retrieve all the rows (data) on every request, would not slow down the processing when the size of data will be huge?

Comment: A queryset doesn't mean all rows.

Comment: @noshii should have made it an answer: retrive -> retrieve

Comment: @SachinKukreja - Isn't @Thaian talking about to add `serializer_class = TestSerializer` and `queryset = TestTB.objects.all()` to the view? Than `TestTB.objects.all()` will retrieve all the rows

Comment: No it won't. Querysets are lazy and don't call the database until evaluated.

Comment: And adding queryset doesnt mean you have to execute `.all()`. It could be any filtered queryset, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `retrive` to `retrieve`. Made an answer out of the comment, as suggested by @Linovia.

Comment: I don't really see a reason it wouldn't work passed this typo which prevents the binding of the detail GET verb with a concrete action.