# Django connection.queries is not running in server

Tags: django, django-models, amazon-ec2

I am executing following code in views.py file on dev server hosted on AWS EC2 instance and my settings.py file has `DEBUG = True` configured.

```
from django.db import connection
from project.models import MyModel

mymodels = MyModel.objects.all()
print("My models: ", mymodels)
raw_queries = connection.queries
print("raw query: ", raw_queries)
```

Output is:

```
My models: [<myModel 1>, <myModel 2>,<myModel 3>]
raw query: []
```

I am not sure, what i am missing. why `raw query = []`.

I tried doing with `python3 manage.py shell` but same thing happend there too. but same result `raw query = []`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133627/using-django-db-connection-queries

Comment: in my case, connection.queries is working on localhost. but not on server

Comment: Check on server if querying your model works and how is database connected ?

Comment: everything is working fine.
Even querset.query is giving results.
does connections.queries not work on server environment

Answer (score 0):

My bad! I am using multiple databases in project. and according to documentation i should have used

```
from django.db import connections
connections['db_name'].queries
```

instead of

```
from django.db import connection
raw_queries = connection.queries
```

Thanks @Ahtisham